# Change size of bullet image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I loaded an image bullet style via a url:

```
var a = document.createElement('li');
a.style.listStyleImage = "url(some url)";
a.style.listStylePosition = "inside";
```

But I want to increase the size of the bullet (image) using Javascript, is that possible?

Comment: Use the background-image property instead, where you can adjust the size, position, etc.

Comment: Per @elclanrs, the correct answer is _don't_.

Comment: @elclanrs I tried passing an image variable to listStyleImage instead of a url (so that I can play with the size), but it didn't work, so how can I do that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned in the comments, `list-style-image` does not support the behaviour you want.

## Using backgrounds

**If you don't have a background already**: Just use the elements `background-image` property isntead.

**If you do have a background already**: In CSS3 it's possible to define multiple backgrounds. This means that you can use the bullet image as an additional non repeating background as well giving you full control over it. Controlling multiple backgrounds though javascript is not a lot of fun though and I haven't heard of any good plugins for it either. You might want to take a look around though, someone might have made something and otherwise just write your own abstraction layer.

## Using data url's

An alternative, more crazy, approach would be to load the image through ajax, draw it onto an canvas scaled in any way you like, generate a data uri from the canvas and set that as the uri of the `list-style-image` property.

Comment: Can you show how I can do it with data url's? And thanks for the help! ^_^

Comment: @user3651766 Could you explain why you would want to go down that route? I only pointed it out because it's technically possible, not because it's a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Use `::before` pseudo class to display bullet

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">test
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">test
    </li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list{
    list-style: none;
}

.list-item::before{
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/20/30);
    background-size: 200%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PtG6Q/1/

Comment: Is it possible using JavaScript only? Can't do it any other way :$ And thanks for the help :))

Comment: Why you can do it by js if you can do it by css?

If you don't have access to css file you always can inject css.

Comment: Can you show how I can inject that specific property given the code I've posted above? Thanks :$

Comment: Oh there are several ways to do it. You can load external file, append style tag, append style to tag. etc... 

Ugly, fast approach will be $("head").append('<style> body{background: red;} </style>')